# Python Tkinter: How do you link a button to open a specific app on Windows 10?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I wanted to create a GUI button using Python Tkinter Module to open up a specific app that has already been installed on the computer, e.g. 'calculator'.

I have found a similar question on StackOverflow but its not quite what I want as it only open the file directory and not the app itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this *what I want as it only open the file directory and not the app itself*

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807817/how-do-i-run-an-exe-from-python-using-a-tkinter-button) what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @Sujay I am trying to create a GUI button using tkinter to open up the calculator app when clicked on it. The post that I found seems to only open up the file explorer with the path of the app but not the app itself.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcq Kind of like that. I'll try to apply it to my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, find the path location of the app you want.
File path for calculator in my system is `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`

So use `webbrowser` to open it -

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

root = tk.Tk()

def open_calc():
    webbrowser.open_new('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe ')

B1 = tk.Button(root,text='hi',command=open_calc)
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll now apply it to my code and try to create a button with the image of the calculator on it.

Comment: BTW, for any other apps, probably you should search google if you cannot find the file paths

Comment: Thank you, this is going to help a lot for my project.

Comment: ok, what? I guess webbrowser's open functionality is the same as `os.startfile()` it just looks a bit odd, so an alternative would be to `import os` and then instead of `webbrowser.open_new('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe ')` use `os.startfile('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe ')` or since using windows might as well do this: `os.system('calc')` instead of all of that path and stuff, tho actually maybe not use `os.system`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the `subprocess` module to create a new process like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from subprocess import Popen

root = tk.Tk()

def open_calc():
    Popen("calc.exe")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Open Calculator", command=open_calc)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This method is more intuitive to me than using `webbrowser`. The `subprocess` module was designed to create new processes

Comment: Thank you, this will save me much in trying to find the directory location. By the way, is there a process in subprocess module to allow images to be easily called in, instead of pasting the whole link to the directory?

Comment: @BartSimpson Are the images in the same directory as the python file?

Comment: Kind of, I put it inside a folder named 'images' within the same directory as my python code file.

Comment: Then you can simply open it using - `PhotoImage(file='images/pics.png')`

Comment: @PCM That isn't going to run with the default windows image viewer and you will need more code that than.

Comment: @BartSimpson For images, (you already found it but) use `os.startfile("images/test.png", "open")`. That means you will be using `os` instead of `subprocess`

Comment: I meant it for displaying on to Tkinter window and not to open the pictures. BTW @BartSimpson , what is the extra '@'

Comment: @PCM Seems I forgot to write add a name after '@'. Don't think I can edit anymore too.